# Add my app as an activity for images

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I've created an App that analyses images based on certain criteria. Now I would like to add my App as an 'Activity' for images, so I can send this image to my App (see WhatsApp, iBooks, ...).

I've tried adding *Document Type*s to Xcode (*public.png*, *public.jpeg* and some others) in Target -> Info and one dummy property, but I did not get my Icon to show up in the 'Share' menu on Safari.

I used [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) to find out about the UTIs I most likely need. I am using Xcode 8 with Swift 3, tested on iOS 10.

I don't really know where to go from here, so any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jan

**Edit:**
By adding 'public.image' I am now able to open image files from the Mail app with mine. It still does not work with Safari images and images from my Photo Library.